# JQuery .data() how to work question

Tags: jquery

I have a question about .data(). In a stackoverflow answer, jquery saves data in cache object where cache index is suffixed with a hash of the dom element. For example, consider an element as:

1. #result ID,
2. in 3rd index of the Jquery cache
3. with a key: "carModel" && value: "Audi"

Now, I read .data() will save the key-value with a hash value of result ID and cache index. Now my question is how jquery hash an arbitrary element in dom?

For example, consider the following html:

```
<div id="begin"> 
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
  <p id="another">another</p>
  <div> <p>
      test p
    </p>
  </div>
  <p id="last">last</p>
<div>
```

Code to assign a value to each:

```
var i=0;

$("p").each( function() {
  $(this).data("value",i);
  ++i;

});
```

Lastly, let's retrieve inner most p element's value:

```
alert( $("div div p").data("value") );
// output correctly => 2
```

---

I want to know how this works? :-) I mean how jquery hashed elements in such a way where they can be retrieved without definite identifier (like element-ID) to them?

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way in which jQuery data works is by storing all the data internal in a variable called `cache`. Each jQuery session creates a "expando" which is basically a random string like `jquery161362319162` specific to that session. This is placed on each object in the DOM such as element.jquery161362319162 with a value of the index in cache.

Here is a very basic example of roughly how it works. This will need a bit more work to add support for multiple data on an element, but you'll get the idea of how it works internally.

```
var cache = []; // Stores all the data for each element
var uid = 'jquery89437507043'; // random generated id,
                               // jQuery uses a function to automatically
                               // generate such a value

function data(element, key, data)
{
    if (data !== undefined) // We are setting data
    {
        var thisCache[key] = data;
        cache.push(thisCache)
        element[uid] = cache.length; // Place the index cache
                                        // for this data set on the element
    }
    else
    {
        return cache[element[uid]][key];
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
var div = $('div').get(0);
data(div, 'test', { 'apple': 'juice' });

alert(data(div, 'test').apple); // Will alert 'juice'
```

Comment: too close but not all :-) still not sure to me how uid value as jquery89437507043 matches exactly with the correct <p> tag

Comment: The uid value is just unique to that jquery session i.e. if you had multiple jqueries running, possibly in iframes or noConflict, each setting their own data on elements, it would still retain their own data set. The value for that uid on each element is the index for where the data to that element is stored in cache. So [element].jquery89437507043 = 85 -- if you look in Firebug you will see this value set on that element in the DOM. 85 is the place in `cache` where the data for that element is stored i.e. `cache[85]` is data that relates to `[element]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have understood what you have done with the JQUERY selectors.

In your example HTML you nested 2 divs and then placed a single paragraph into the lowest level div. Then in your JQUERY you asked it to look for 2 divs and a paragraph. That's why you got the "correct" result. This actually has nothing to do with `.data()` as such, but the fact that there wasn't anything else for JQUERY to find, and therefore the result was always going to be "correct".

However, I'm not certain you would get the "correct" result if you had a larger context with many nested divs that had no id values.

I would say that it is good practice for you to assign an id value for all your `<div>` and then pass the specific id whenever you use `.data()`.

In that way you can know what the outcome of your code will be as you create it.

Comment: You got me wrong...I made such div structure intentionally. My question was: How Jquery identify element correctly to retrieve value? Here the nested most div has value 2, but it was set without any ID. So when jquery correctly returned value for this, my question comes to ask: Why this <p> and no ther <p> ?............Another way of asking: Every <p> is identical when their value was set, isn't it? So how they are differentiated when their value is retrieved?