# Is there a way to hash a html dom element for use in a map?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, hash

I'm trying to store some data against a html dom element and don't want to rely on attributes set on the element. So, is there a way to hash a html dom element for use in a map ?

Example, I want to be able to do the following in javascript:

```
Map[Hash(DIV1)] = somedata;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you "don't want to rely on attributes set on the element" ?

Comment: Can't you use IDs on the HTML elements?

Comment: @Incognito: I'm trying to keep the DOM clean which is needed because I'm trying to generate HTML that can be copy pasted by user to his project. So if I keep any properties on the element for tracking (while the user interacts with them - a kind of WYSIWYG editor), I have to clean up later.

Comment: @Fabian: For the same reason I gave to Incognito, I can't use IDs

Comment: You may want something like jQuery's `data()`. You can start investigating here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948099/jquery-data-how-to-work-question although I can't provide a full answer

Comment: How do you plan to distinguish two identical pieces of HTML from each other? If you have two divs with the same HTML ex: "<div>100</div>" & "<div>100</div>", then throwing them into a hashing algorithm will generate the same hash.

Comment: @WalterStabosz We can probably take parent element, children and siblings into consideration but I'm hoping some one has already solved this before or thought of an algorithm :)

Comment: I think you interpret me saying set the attribute on the element as changing the value of the `<tag>`. I'm saying take the node and apply the value to the DOM node object.

Comment: @Incognito Yup, sorry about that :( didn't light my bulb till I saw Charles's answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could append the data directly to the div.

```
var nextID = 1;

var hash = function(div){
   div.hashID = div.hashID || ('hashID_' + (nextID++));
   return div.hashID;
}
```

Comment: Is this same as setting an attribute on the element ? I was under the (mistaken) impression that this creates a attribute on the DOM tree (like 'id' or 'src' or 'class' etc)..

Comment: This adds a property to the element object in the js runtime not the DOM.